# Cannot save a matrix in the GUI but I can save the same matrix to the same folder in the command window

Tags: matrix, save

```
`    keyboard
    try
    save writePath mOrg
    catch 
      warning(err.identifier, err.message);
      keyboard;
    end_try_catch

 `
```

When I copy the third line to the command window, the file with mOrg matrix is saved and is OK. When I execute it in the GUI-editor window, it is not saved and I do not receive an error message!
The writePath is a long path: D:\DATA-MEDION\bros\autoDwn\stommeUp2Date\crommejan.m.txt.dbl stored in a variable with class char and size 1,52 which was the length of the name.
With this code :
    `writePath=strcat('D:\',name,'.mat');
     save writePath mOrg` % NOT Ok `

With this code: 
     `save  'D:\DATA-MEDION\bros\autoDwn\stommeUp2Date\test.mat' mOrg % OK`
Problem seems to come from the fact that the path name is in a variable...

Comment: PS. 'name' above was the filename part of the path.

Comment: Solved with     save ([up2dateDir,name,'.mat'],'mOrg' ) ;